# React Jest DynamoDb Testing throws error ENOENT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb

I get the following error when trying to run my jest tests:

```
> jest

    Determining test suites to run...events.js:292
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    Error: spawn java ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
      errno: -4058,
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'spawn java',
      path: 'java',
      spawnargs: [
        '-Xrs',
        '-Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib',
        '-jar',
        'DynamoDBLocal.jar',
        '-port',
        8000,
        '-sharedDb',
        '-inMemory'
      ]
    }
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

On other devices its working with the same code, so it has to do something with the installations, maybe something is missing or broken?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html):

> To run DynamoDB on your computer, you must have the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 8.x or newer. The application doesn't run on earlier JRE versions.

Looks like you don't have Java installed on your machine.